# (Python) How to use driver.find_element_by_link_text when two texts are there in between <a> tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML

```
<a href="/hyperlink" ><span class="gl11">text1</span> <br /><span class="UC">text2</span></a>
```

I want to get the hyperlink and click on it. I write:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('text')
link.click()
```

But the problem is there are two texts in between "a" tag. How do I modify the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('text1\ntext2')
link.click()
```

There is also possibility to find element by `"text1"` or `"text2"` using `find_element_by_partial_link_text()`:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('text1')
link.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your second code will work, only difference is it will give results only if "text" is in uppercase "TEXT". Looks weird though.